# How can i make the horizontal navigation menu center aligned

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, themes

I am creating a Wordpress theme based on the Twenty Eleven theme and can't figure out how to have the navigation bar center automatically so I won't have to constantly update it.

Here is my CSS:
http://pastebin.com/SGvKmXEb

Here is the PHP/HTML:
http://pastebin.com/TBL1nzjV

There may be duplicate properties in the CSS, but only because I am still experimenting with this and testing multiple things...

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the CSS and markup you are using. IF your links or the content on the links change in the future then this question will still provide all the information needed to help other users find a solution to similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked for me on the test site you provided

```
#access li {

float: left; /*delete*/
display:block; /*delete*/

display:inline-block; /*add*/

}

#access ul {

margin-left: 25%; /*delete*/
margin-right: 25%; /*delete*/
width: 1000px; /*delete*/
height: 10px; /*delete*/

margin-bottom: 0px; /*add*/
margin-left: 0px; /*add*/
padding: 0px; /*add*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd choose an inline-block approach.

```
.containerElement {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.childElements {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

In order to make it work in your code, you need to remove ***.containerElement*** (#access ul) fixed height, and ***.childElements*** (#access li) floating property.

Comment: I already tried this and nothing different happens - here is a sample of what it looks like: http://yenrac.net